# Terminal app on Ubuntu Touch nexus 4

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-touch

I want to install the Terminal app on Ubuntu touch.
When I ssh to the nexus4 device and run `sudo apt-get install terminal` I get this error.

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Comment: Looks like this is a problem with sudo. Can you sudo any other commands?

Answer (score 1):

The package you want is `ubuntu-terminal-app`, but it's been installed by default in the device images for weeks now.  Try going to the Apps lens and using the search (upper-left corner) to find it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I opened qtcreator and went to tools, ubuntu touch device control and went to ssh to device. Worked like a charm. I install the terminal app and file manager app. I then went to search on the apps screen and found them. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script which I use to add a load of applications post-flashing. You might want to try it:-

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~popey/+junk/phablet-flash-wrapper/view/head:/post-flash.sh

Line 57 has the important bit, where it specifies which apps to install. You might want to trim (or expand) that list. I added the touch-coreapps and touch-collection PPAs and all the apps along with ssh, vnstat and pastebinit.

Comment: Do I have to move the post-flash.sh to my phone to run it. Can i move a movie file to the phone as well. (mp4) I not sure how to do this.

Comment: no. you run it on your pc